# How can I fix issue on adding a cordova platform?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I have a project which was developed two years ago from an other developer.

Now I try to add platforms to this Cordova project. I am an newbie in things of developing mobile apps.

If I add platforms like IOS, Android or Browser I get always the same error message.

```
Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
```

I have Cordova "8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)" installed via

```
sudo npm -g install cordova
```

The following error message I get if I add a platform

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/restore-util.js:322:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.installPluginsFromConfigXML (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/restore-util.js:318:28)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:58:32
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
```

The part in file "restore-util.js:322:57" look like this:

```
    // Check to see if pkg.json plugin(id) and config plugin(id) match.
    if (comboPluginIdArray.toString() !== pluginIdConfig.toString()) {
        // If there is a config plugin that does NOT already exist in
        // comboPluginIdArray, add it and its variables.
        pluginIdConfig.forEach(function (item) {
            if (comboPluginIdArray.indexOf(item) < 0) {
                comboPluginIdArray.push(item);
                var configXMLPlugin = cfg.getPlugin(item);
                comboObject[item] = configXMLPlugin.variables;
                modifiedPkgJson = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Now I fix my issue:

1. Remove all installed plugins from config.xml and package.json
2. Remove node_modules folder
3. Remove folders android, ios, browser from /platforms
4. Install all plugins with cordova plugin install
5. Run npm install
6. At least build platforms cordova platform add

I'm not sure, maybe some deprecated versions of plugins was installed. So I reinstall every plugin in project. I work since two days with ionic, cordova/phonegap and I think I will learn from day to day more about this topic.

Comment: whats the version of the ionic project ?

Comment: Is there any more in the error message, like a stack trace pointing to the location of `variables`?

Comment: @yushin how can i check the version?

Comment: @simon-l-brazell I add some trace content which displayed on adding a platform, exists any other debug or log file?